# How to draw a filled polygon using Graphics

Tags: c#, asp.net

Within the System.Drawing.Graphics namespace you can draw a polygon like this:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
  g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Black, myArray);
}
```

and there is a method to create a filled polygon `g.FillPolygon()`.

How can you create a polygon (so it has a border) and then fill it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just draw the filled polygon then draw the perimeter so it looks like it has a border:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.FillPolygon(fillBrush, myArray);
    g.DrawPolygon(borderPen, myArray);
}
```